# Is there a simple way to map snmp(MIB) strings to OIDs in Perl?

Tags: perl, snmp, oid

Is there a simple way/module to map snmp(MIB) strings to OIDs in Perl?

E.g. I start with "sysUpTime.0" and get "1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0". As far as I can see, Net::SNMP expects you to have them already mapped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [NetSNMP::OID](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?NetSNMP::OID) to do the conversion.

```
use NetSNMP::OID;

my $oid = NetSNMP::OID->new('sysUpTime.0');
```

NetSNMP::OID is part of the [Net-SNMP project](http://net-snmp.sourceforge.net/), not to be confused with the [Net::SNMP module](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net::SNMP).

Comment: NetSNMP::OID doesn't compile for me, and at least for ubuntu I can't find a package.

Comment: @Sec: you can install directly from CPAN; there are posts about this on SO with more information if you have questions about this process.

Comment: I _was_ using "perl -MCPAN -e 'install NetSNMP::OID'".

Comment: Try downloading Net-SNMP from sourceforge and using it.  Worked like a charm for me with Ubuntu 8.4.